# $N$ kids with $k$ balls. Reshuffle. Find distribution of number of balls brought back by same kids when $N \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$N$ kids each brought $k$ balls to a party. When they leave each kid brings back $k$ balls randomly. Let $X$ be the total number of balls brought back by their original owners. We fix $k$. Find the distribution of $X$ when $N \rightarrow \infty$

[EDIT, removed my earlier incorrect attempt] As the comment pointed out when $k=1$ it's a rather simple Poisson distribution. But how do we prove this case for arbitrary $k$?

Comment: Interesting question!  But consider $k=1$ and we have $E[X] = 1$ but $X \ge 0$.  I'm guessing $X$ is much more like Poisson than like Gaussian.

Comment: @antkam very good point. How do we prove it's a Poisson though..

Comment: Here it's shown that the (very special) case $k=1$ (which amounts to counting derangements) tends to a Poisson https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/fixed-points-of-random-permutations/

I would bet that here we also have a Poisson, but it looks difficult to prove.

Comment: I am 80% confident this is in Feller volume 1.  Why is the original post tagged as 'solution-verification' when no work is shown?

Comment: @user8675309 i originally offered an incorrect solution that was pointed out by the comments. I have removed my solution and the solution verification tag now

Comment: Are the $k$ balls from each kid distinguable?

Comment: @LogicalGooGoo indistinguishable in a sense that that order of the balls don't matter as long as they got brought back by same kid. But certainly we know which ball belongs to whom

Comment: Do you know if the result can be expressed in closed form? I've come up with something that has a series (and generating functions). Once I'm trying to make it more compact I'll post it here.

Comment: @LogicalGooGoo I don't know. I just know it's apparently from this math contest in 2019.. you have to go through some chinese links but the problems are all English.  http://yau-contest.com/index/reldown?id=7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution you want should be Poisson(k) and this should follow from Stein-Chen method. (I will be referring to [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~psdey/414CourseNotes.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Epsdey/414CourseNotes.pdf))

Imagine each student kept $k$ buckets in front of them, and then after the reshuffling, checked whether the bucket contained a ball of theirs. We then have $kn$ Bernoulli random variables, each with probability of success 1/n. Now, we have

$$W = \sum_{i=1}^{kn} 1_i$$

We note that most of these random variables are positively correlated, since if we return someone's ball to them, buckets belonging to others are likelier to have their owners' balls. There are some of them that are negatively correlated though, which means we cannot use any of the results in that PDF directly; however, a small modification should still get the job done.

For $Y_j^i$, we consider the coupling that is induced by at first fixing bucket $i$ to have its owner's ball, and then swapping u.a.r. (analogous to Example 8.3 on the PDF linked above.)

We thus have

\begin{align}
p_i E[|U_i - V_i|] &\leq E[|X_i + \sum_{j \neq i} - Y_j^i| \\
&\leq p_i E[X_i] + \sum_{O(j) \neq O(i)} p_i E(Y_j^i - X_j) + \sum_{j \neq i, O(j) = O(i)} p_i E[X_j - Y_j^i]\\
&\leq E[X_i]^2 + \sum_{O(j) \neq O(i)} E[X_i X_j] - E[X_i]E[X_j]) \\
&- \sum_{j \neq i, O(j) = O(i)} E[X_i X_j]  - E[X_i] E[X_j]
\end{align}

Now, we can evaluate both sums:

$$\sum_{O(j) \neq O(i)} E[X_i X_j] - E[X_i]E[X_j]) = k(n-1) (\frac{k^2}{(nk)(nk-1)}  - \frac{1}{n^2} ) = \frac{k^2 (n-1)}{n^2 (k^2 n - k)} = O(n^2) $$

$$\sum_{j \neq i, O(j) = O(i)} E[X_i X_j]  - E[X_i] E[X_j] =  (k-1) (\frac{k(k-1)}{nk (nk-1) } - \frac{1}{n^2}) = O(n^3)$$

and then, summing it up, we see that the overall TV distance to a Poisson of rate $\lambda = \sum_{i}^{kn} 1/n = k$ can be bounded by order O(1/n).

Comment: Could you explain what $U_i, V_i, O(i)$ are since the link is dead?